# Using OpenOffice sCalc - How to use IF function with REGEX capture and if true print capture to cell

Tags: regex, openoffice-calc

I have a worksheet (OpenOffice sCalc) with many rows of data, MOST of them have a year enclosed in ()

One of the cell's has this content: Mary had a little lamb, Sarah Josepha Hale (1830)

I would like to capture the year and save it in the cell to the right.

This stmt will tell me if a year is present:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(L115; ".*[(][0-9]{4,4}[)].*");"hooray"; "boo")
```

When I try to replace "Hooray" with $1 in this stmt I get an error:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(L115; ".*([(][0-9]{4,4}[)]).*");$1; "boo")
```

I get this: #REF!

What is the correct syntax? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex capturing is possible in Search/replace (must be enabled under "More Options"), but I don't know if you can use capturing in formulae.

An alternative way:

```
=VALUE(MID(L115;FIND("(";L115)+1;4))
```

Comment: This will work, but in those instances where the date is not enclosed in () what would the stmt. be? I have tried several variations but I keep getting errors.

Comment: Please post examples of all the format variations of your data, then maybe we can make a formula. E.g. finding a 4 digit number within a cell can be done with `=VALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH("\d{4}",A1),4))`. (Looks like `SEARCH` supports regexes but `FIND` does not.)

Comment: Weiss and Kline, Excavating, 14,1 (1962)
Weiss and Kline, Excavating, 14,1 1962
It would be great to have a solution that works in both instances. What I have done was to export the sheet as a csv file, then insert the year into the correct column with Perl, then re-import it into sCalc - not elegant but it works

Comment: Try `=VALUE(MID(A1;SEARCH("[0-9]{4}";A1);4))`. (Doesn't seem to support character class `\d`.) This gets the first occurrence of 4 digits.